# How to get the time difference from dutyoff to dutyon of AM and PM?

Tags: c#, datatable

[updated attendance data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF0vS.png)

We're stuck of this function on how to get the total hours of time column, what we want is, the duty off minus the time of duty on from morning time, as well as the afternoon time so that we can sum the hours of the time column. 
And we want to display the total to the last row of time column.

[sample attendance data scrshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLro2.png)

```
//display attendance data from database
    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ralph\Documents\User.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"); ;

        // SqlDataAdapter adapSel;

        conn.Open();
        //SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from AMPS  where DateandTime >= '" + dtpFrom.Value.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "' AND DateandTime <= '" + dtpTo.Value.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "'", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT WorkersInfo.WorkersID, WorkersInfo.LName, WorkersInfo.FName, WorkersInfo.MName, WorkersInfo.Position, WorkersInfo.Salary, AMPS.InandOut, cast(DateandTime as date) [Date], RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateandTime, 100),7) as Time FROM AMPS INNER JOIN WorkersInfo ON AMPS.EnNo = WorkersInfo.WorkersID where DateandTime between '" + dtpFrom.Value.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "' and '" + dtpTo.Value.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "'", conn);
        DataGridViewColumn InandOut = grdList.Columns[6];
        InandOut.Width = 100;
        DataGridViewColumn DateandTime = grdList.Columns[7];//column DateandTime
        DateandTime.Width = 145;
        DataGridViewColumn MName = grdList.Columns[3];//column MiddleName
        MName.Width = 50;//changing the column width

        //da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        grdList.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void DisplayData()
    {
        CON.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT WorkersInfo.WorkersID, WorkersInfo.LName, WorkersInfo.FName, WorkersInfo.MName, WorkersInfo.Position, WorkersInfo.Salary, AMPS.InandOut, AMPS.DateandTime FROM AMPS INNER JOIN WorkersInfo ON AMPS.EnNo = WorkersInfo.WorkersID", CON);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        grdList.DataSource = dt;
        CON.Close();
    }

    private void grdList_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        txtWorkersID.Text = grdList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtLast_Name.Text = grdList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + ", " + grdList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + ", " + grdList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtPosition.Text = grdList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtDRate.Text = grdList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        //cboGender.Text = grdWorkers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    }
```

but we are stuck on how to calculate the number of hours or time difference from dutyoff to dutyon

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using DateTime and TimeSpan.  Your SQL query actually splits the DateandTime object into separate date and time columns. You can reconstitute the DateTime in C# or just pull the additional column from the query.

```
DateTime timeOut = x;//use your dateandtime column value here for time out
DateTime timeIn = y;//same here for time in

TimeSpan timeSpan = timeOut.Subtract(timeIn);
```

You can then access:

```
timeSpan.Hours;
timeSpan.Minutes;
timeSpan.Seconds;
```

If you loop through all of your entries and calculate 2 timespans per day, then add them together you will get values for the total time spent by a worker.

UPDATE: To loop through the data table you could something like this, but note, it has a lot of assumptions and you should probably change the structure of your data table if possible.  I would have one row with an in time and out time, rather than having to cycle through each entry and find the corresponding in entry and out entry. But that depends on if you can change the underlying database).

All that said, after you have filled your DataTable - I'd do something like:

```
foreach (var dateGroup in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(dg => dg[7])) //this groups your entries by date
        {
            TimeSpan totalTimeForDate = new TimeSpan(0);
            var ins = dateGroup.Where(dg => dg[6].ToString() == "DutyOn").OrderBy(dg => dg[8]).ToList();//this gets your dutyins and orders by time
            var outs = dateGroup.Where(dg => dg[6].ToString() == "DutyOff").OrderBy(dg => dg[8]).ToList();//this gets your dutyoffs and orders by time

            for (int inOutCounter = 0; inOutCounter < ins.Count(); inOutCounter++)
            {
                DateTime timeIn = DateTime.Parse(ins[inOutCounter][7].ToString() + ins[8].ToString()); //you will need to modify this to parse the date correctly, 
                DateTime timeOut = DateTime.Parse(outs[inOutCounter][7].ToString() + outs[8].ToString()); //or change you sql query to bring back the datetime in another column and parse that

                totalTimeForDate += timeOut.Subtract(timeIn);

                //You will need to do some error handling in here in case there are missing entries
                //This code assumes there is always an out time to match an in time
            }

            //here you can now access:
            var hours = totalTimeForDate.Hours;
            var minutes = totalTimeForDate.Minutes;
            var seconds = totalTimeForDate.Seconds;
        }
```

Comment: Can you teach us how to loop all of our entries in my table? We really need your help. And in your given code, I think timein and timeout are column headers too. But, our sample data is different, dutyon and dutyoff is not a column header that's why we're having a hard time on how to code it.. Hope you can help us..

Comment: You would need to be able to pair up a TimeIn and a TimeOut row.  I will update code but you will be able to cycle through the dt.dataSet I think. one sec